# VPS does not connect to external systems "Server responded with a non-101 status: 403 Forbidden"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket, bots

Recently I created a bot for myself that captures data from a betting house and performs analyzes to help me with decisions, this bot was primarily running on my computer, but I needed it to be connected directly without stopping and I transferred it to a Raspberry Pi 3, I spent a few months this way and felt the need to put it on a VPS due to the fact that the internet is dedicated because at my house it sometimes crashed and caused an error in the bot. However, when I run the bot there the bookmaker blocks the connection, which is allowed on my machine, they block it and return:
`Error: Server responded with a non-101 status: 403 Forbidden Response Headers Follow: date: Sun, 24 Mar 2024 18:22:59 GMT content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 content-length: 4515 connection: keep-alive x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN referrer-policy: same-origin cache-control: max-age=15 expires: Sun, 24 Mar 2024 18:23:14 GMT server: cloudflare cf-ray: 8698b0956c492d9d-ORD`

I don't understand much about networks so I have no idea why this happens, my bot is made in nodejs and the connection is via websocket.

My vps is an AWS EC2 virtual machine that uses Ubuntu.

To solve this, I tried to put the same parameters in the request header that are sent in the browser and it still didn't work.

```
const generateWebSocket = (func) => {
    const client = new WebSocket({
        headers: {
            'Host': 'api-v2.******.space',
            'Connection': 'Upgrade',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept-Language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.5',
            'Upgrade': 'websocket',
            'Origin': 'https://******.space',
            'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Sec-WebSocket-Key': 'JjQKP7TvCpgscpTAv4Q4FA==',
            'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits'
        }
    });
    let operator = 0;

    client.on('connect', async (connection) => {
        console.info('Conexão a ***** foi estabelecida.');

        connection.send(msg1);
        connection.send(msg2);

        connection.on('message', func);

        
        if (operator == 0){
            operator ++;
            scheduleNextMessage(connection);
            scheduleNextMessageHour(connection);
        }
    });

    return client
}
```

Comment: Many websites block access from the IP address range assigned to Amazon EC2 instances specifically to block scraping attempts. Please check the Terms & Conditions of the website to see whether your actions are permitted. We do not encourage violating the Terms & Conditions of websites. If your actions are permitted, then you should contact the owners of the website and ask why the EC2 address range is being blocked.

Comment: I looked into it and it's really not allowed, I didn't know that, thanks for responding

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I opened a chat with the company and they said that the data is free to use and that there would be no problem using it, but they couldn't answer me if there is this blocking of EC2 machines. So, how can I get around this knowing that they have allowed its use but it still gives a 403 forbidden error

Comment: You can't. It is _their_ website that is doing the blocking. You'd have to run it from outside of EC2.

Comment: Understood, I'll see if they have an API